# KeystoneJS v4 on NodeJS v7 on Openshift - MemoryStore is not designed for production environment

Tags: node.js, openshift, keystonejs

I am trying to deploy the KeystoneJS app on Openshift running the latest NodeJS (v7) and after facing some other problems I ran into this error message

```
Mongo Error:
Error: connection closed
    at exports.ConnectionPool.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/5816407e89f5cfcee800001c/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:608:24)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at exports.ConnectionPool.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at exports.Connection.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/5816407e89f5cfcee800001c/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:171:15)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at exports.Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/5816407e89f5cfcee800001c/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:550:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:501:12)
/var/lib/openshift/5816407e89f5cfcee800001c/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/mount.js:630
                        throw new Error('KeystoneJS (' + keystone.get('name') + ') failed to start');
                        ^
Error: KeystoneJS (XYZ Web) failed to start
    at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/5816407e89f5cfcee800001c/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/mount.js:630:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.error (/var/lib/openshift/5816407e89f5cfcee800001c/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:389:8)
    at /var/lib/openshift/5816407e89f5cfcee800001c/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:416:14
    at /var/lib/openshift/5816407e89f5cfcee800001c/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js:57:21
    at /var/lib/openshift/5816407e89f5cfcee800001c/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:286:18
    at /var/lib/openshift/5816407e89f5cfcee800001c/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:365:7
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
{ Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:472:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:420:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:500:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/5816407e89f5cfcee800001c/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js:15:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:500:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/5816407e89f5cfcee800001c/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/index.js:3:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
Got SIGTERM, stopping workers...
(node:20870) DeprecationWarning: Using Buffer without `new` will soon stop working. Use `new Buffer()`, or preferably `Buffer.from()`, `Buffer.allocUnsafe()` or `Buffer.alloc()` instead.
```

I am not really sure, which one of these error messages could be the root cause. Did anybody have similar problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Shimon

Answer (score 0):

You need start MongoDB on the another tab

```
 ~: mongod
```

, and 
Go to the file (in your project):

```
'node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js'
```

and change

```
bson = require('../build/Release/bson');
```

to

```
bson = require('bson');
```

but after you have another problem :

> DeprecationWarning: Using Buffer without `new` will soon stop
>   working. Use `new Buffer()`, or preferably `Buffer.from()`,
>   `Buffer.allocUnsafe()` or `Buffer.alloc()` instead.

it is not Error but localhost:3000 don't run, and what do with it, I don't know